# Cookie not saved for some users

Tags: javascript, cookies

When user registers we want to save the referrer also. If document.referrer is not blank then store it to cookie else store current page href to cookie. But around 2-3 customers per day dont have referrer saved. One reason for this could be that they have cookies disabled, but this is not true since they logged in and were using our website. The question is why this code works for some customers but not others?

```
app.saveReferrer = function () {
    if (Cookies.get('referrer') == undefined || 
        Cookies.get('referrer') == '' || 
        Cookies.get('referrer') == 'undefined') 
    {
        if (document.referrer == undefined || 
            document.referrer == '' || 
            document.referrer == 'undefined') 
        {
            Cookies.set('referrer', document.location.href);
        } else {
            Cookies.set('referrer', document.referrer)
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Ingognito-mode?

Comment: How long are your cookies set to live for? If its a week and the user logs in after a week + a day the cookie will have been deleted. And if its a Month and the user logs in after a Month and a day .... etc etc

Comment: Cookies are a terrible way to persist data reliably

Comment: Cookies are set to live for a week, problem is with fresh customers

Comment: Incognito mode still uses cookies so if he registers in incognito mode it should still be fine

Answer (score 0):

A Cookie can be edited or removed at any point in time. If you're only checking the referrer and setting the cookie during their registration, few possible cases are:

- The customer cleared his cookie after registering
- The customer is using another device
- The customer manually removed the cookie
- The customer logged in on an existing account, skipping the registration (and therefore cookie setting phase)

In order to find out exactly why or how does a specific customer not have a cookie, we would need more information.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer Anton. I realize that cookie can be edited, but our customers are not tech-savvy people so it is highly unlikely.

Comment: Even if your customers did not knowingly edited the cookies, if they logged in with an existing account or used a different device, unless you also set the cookie at these area, the cookie will be empty.

Comment: If customer used another device and it runs javascript then referrer still should be saved. According to code any user should always have cookie referrer, but turns out it does not work as expected, and I am wondering if there is a problem with that code.

Comment: Is this code only on the registration page or on all pages?

Comment: it is put to run on all pages

Comment: is the cookie empty or nonexistant?

Comment: Field in database is empty as a result. Since I dont have access to customers machines I dont know if the cookies is empty or nonexistant.